# Read data from multiple tables at a time and combine the data based where clause using Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have scenario where I need to extract multiple database table data including schema and combine(combination data) them and then write to xl file?

Comment: @mattyb , would be possible to share some light on this? and also if any reference template is available, point to  me to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NiFi the general strategy to read in from a something like a fact table with ExecuteSQL or some other SQL processor, then using LookupRecord to enrich the data with a lookup table. The thing in NiFi is that you can only do a table at a time, so you'd need one LookupRecord for each enrichment table. You could then write to a CSV file that you could open in Excel. There might be some extensions elsewhere that can write directly to Excel but I'm not aware of any in the standard NiFi distro.

Comment: Hi mattyb, Thanks for the information provided, so if there are  4 tables, then we have to use 4 ExecuteSQL processors and 4 LookupRecord  for each lookup table?

Comment: If you have 4 total tables, you should be able to use 1 ExecuteSQL followed by 3 LookupRecords (to get each of the remaining tables' data "joined" into the first table)